# How can I tell if the flash hardware is open on my android camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, hardware, camera-flash

I am developing an app for the Samsung Galaxy Camera 2. Unlike most android devices, this device has a hardware button to open and close the camera's flash. I would like the app to tell the user to open the flash before they take a picture, if the flash mode is on.  However i can not detect if the camera's flash is opened or closed. The flash button does not register as a key event so I do not know how else to detect when this hardware button is being used.

Comment: Does the available flash modes list that you get back from `Camera.Parameters` change based upon whether the flash is open or closed?

Comment: No, the flash modes do not change.i also printed out camera.getParameters().flatten() and all the parameters were the same no matter if the flash was opened or closed.

Comment: Then you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFlashMode()

try `getFlashMode();`

Comment: already tried that, the flash modes are independent of the hardware button